# How to publish Angular Libraries in Azure DevOps Artifacts feed?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, feed, azure-artifacts

I am trying to publish some **Angular Libraries** in an **Azure DevOps Artifacts feed** using an **Azure Pipeline yaml**, but i have a problem with authentication.

I implemented two solutions but both don't work.

## Using .npmrc file

As suggested in feed section, i created the **.npmrc** file:

```
registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/ORGANIZATION/PROJECT/_packaging/FEED/npm/registry/

always-auth=true
```

Then i created the following **yaml**:

```
trigger:
  batch: true # disable concurrent build for pipeline
  branches:
    include:
      - main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

stages:

  - stage: Publish
    displayName: 'Publish Stage'

    jobs:
      - job: execute_publish
        displayName: 'Publish Job'

        steps:

          - task: NodeTool@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '18.13.x'
            displayName: 'Install node.js'

          - task: NpmAuthenticate@0
            inputs:
              workingFile: '.npmrc'
            displayName: 'Authenticate with Azure DevOps NPM feed'

          - script: |
              npm install
            displayName: 'Install dependencies'

          - script: |
              npm run test
            displayName: 'Execute tests'

          - script: |
              npm run publish:LIBRARY
            displayName: 'Publish LIBRARY'
```

Where the `npm run publish:LIBRARY` is a script in the **package.json**

```
"publish:LIBRARY": "cd ./projects/LIBRARY && npm version patch && ng build && cd ../../dist/LIBRARY && npm publish",
```

All commands in a local environment work, but the **pipeline fails**:

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for RANDOM-PACKAGE.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

## Split in two stages

As a second solution, i try to **split build and publish** in two different stages.

**Without using .npmrc file**, this was the **yaml**:

```
trigger:
  batch: true # disable concurrent build for pipeline
  branches:
    include:
      - '*'  # CI start for all branches

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

stages:

  - stage: Build
    displayName: 'Build Stage'
    condition: eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')

    jobs:
      - job: execute_build
        displayName: 'Build Job'

        steps:

          - task: NodeTool@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '18.13.x'
            displayName: 'Install node.js'

          - script: |
              npm config set registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
            displayName: 'Set public registry'

          - script: |
              npm install
            displayName: 'Install dependencies'

          - script: |
              npm run test
            displayName: 'Execute tests'

          - script: |
              npm run build:LIBRARY
            displayName: 'Build LIBRARY'

  - stage: Publish
    displayName: 'Publish Stage'
    dependsOn: Build

    jobs:
      - job: execute_publish
        displayName: 'Publish Job'

        steps:

          - task: NodeTool@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '18.13.x'
            displayName: 'Install node.js'

          - script: |
              echo "registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/ORGANIZATION/PROJECT/_packaging/FEED/npm/registry/" > .npmrc
              echo "always-auth=true" >> .npmrc
            displayName: 'Cerate .npmrc file'

          - task: NpmAuthenticate@0
            inputs:
              workingFile: '.npmrc'
            displayName: 'Authenticate with Azure DevOps NPM feed'

          - script: |
              cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/dist/LIBRARY/
              npm publish
            displayName: 'Publish LIBRARY'

          - script: rm .npmrc
            displayName: 'Remove .npmrc file'
```

Where the `npm run build:LIBRARY` is a script in the **package.json**:

`"publish:LIBRARY": "cd ./projects/LIBRARY && npm version patch && ng build && cd ../../dist/LIBRARY && npm pack",`

Build Stage succeded, but **Publish Stage fails**:

```
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in to https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/Jakala/DataAlliance/_packaging/frontend-feed/npm/registry/:_authToken=fyvsmbutef7ot2n275hfgq3hcih2dinn3scrbvd6osvovb2ozfsa
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`
```

**what is the correct way** to implement this publication task?

Thank You